# Magento observer get all order details?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to get all of the order details after an order is placed in my observer however it's not showing up. Is there a certain event I have to use? Or some sort of order detail im missing?

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate>
    </modules>

    <!-- Configure our module's behavior in the global scope -->
    <global>

        <!-- Defining models -->
        <models>

            <!--
                Unique identifier in the model's node.
                By convention, we put the module's name in lowercase.
            -->
            <smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>

                <!--
                    The path to our models directory, with directory
                    separators replaced by underscores
                -->
                <class>SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model</class>

            </smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>

        </models>

        <events> 
            <checkout_submit_all_after>
                <observers>
                    <smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
                        <class>SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>logUpdate</method>
                    </smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
                </observers>
            </checkout_submit_all_after>
        </events>  


    </global>

</config>
```

Observer.php

```
class SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Magento passes a Varien_Event_Observer object as
     * the first parameter of dispatched events.
     */
    public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       //Get Info
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        Mage::log(
            "{$order}",
            null, 
            'product-updates.log'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using Magento event `sales_order_place_after` for this purpose and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your config to

```
 ...
     <events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>logproductupdate/observer</class>
                    <method>logUpdate</method>
                </smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
 ...
```

Comment: the event is firing and it's writing to the log file. so i dont think the config file is the issue. This is what my log looks like though:

2013-12-09T22:24:24+00:00 DEBUG (7):

Comment: What is it exactly are you trying to do? To update a field just do $order->setData('fieldname', 'value')`

Comment: i'm trying to get all the order information after someone clicks submit order to send it over to another API. Such as the products in the order and customer information such as name and shipping address.

Comment: Try `Mage::log($order->getData(), NULL, 'product-updates.log');`